# Is it possible to hide passed parameters in url while using redirect in controller? Yii 1.1

Tags: model-view-controller, yii

I am trying to pass parameter from my controller to my view.
My code is like this:

```
$this->redirect(array('marketingEmail/mailToSend','lot'=>$lotNum));

public function actionMailToSend()
{ 
   $lotValue = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('lot');
   $model=new Marketing();
   $this->render('_mailList',array(
        'lotVal'=>$lotValue,'model'=>$model,
   ));
}
```

My current url is like: http://localhost/test/marketingEmail/mailToSend/lot/1.

I want my url like: http://localhost/test/marketingEmail/mailToSend.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

You can use session variable for your purpose. Save your id in session and get this id in your redirected page.

For more solution you can refer [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/18128-redirect-with-post/) URL.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to make HTTP POST redirect using PHP. The only way to do it using user's browser side. For example generate page with form and submit it from `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use curl_exec on a REST API function that accepts a POST.

David Walsh wrote an article in 2008 entitled: [Execute a HTTP POST Using PHP CURL](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post)

Quoting from the blog post:

```
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Otherwise, use javascript.